# Where can I find an item I can disenchant to learn Fortify Alchemy?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've been reading all sorts of things about people "gamebreaking" and crafting ultimate everythings. I wanted to join in, but I can't seem to find an item to disenchant so as to get the Fortify Alchemy enchantment (that I would use to craft fortify enchantment and so on...).

Does anyone know where I can find what I'm looking for?

Comment: afaik its a random enchantment that appears on certain armor types, most I've seen were gloves, a few were on circlets and helmets.  If there's a guaranteed place with one of those it'd be nice to know.

Comment: I don't think there is any secret, I've seen it mostly on gloves too -- just check every smith and every merchant who carries random magical items

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I was searching for an enchant I needed, I did the following.

1. Check Riverwood blacksmith for enchantment.
2. Fast travel to Whiterun Stables, rest until afternoon when the Kajiit vendor is outside the walls, and check for the enchantment.
3. Fast travel to Whiterun and check the blacksmith for the enchantment.
4. Fast travel to each Imperial/Stormcloak camp I had access to and checked their blacksmiths for the enchantment.
5. Fast travel back to Riverwood. Wait (rest) for two 24-hour periods.
6. Repeat the whole process as necessary.

Alternatively, you could sit at one vendor, check what they are selling, then just wait two 24-hour periods and check again.  Sometimes it can take a while.

I think some enchantments might not show up until you reach a certain level.  I have a level 41 and he has not seen the fiery soul trap enchantment yet.

Depending on the enchant, make sure you have a couple thousand septim or you might end up doing all the waiting and finding you don't have the cash to get the item with the enchant you desire.

For the enchant you specifically mention... you might want to try the quest Jonathan Drain mentioned in his post.

Comment: i had been looking for this item for weeks before i tried this. I waited twice and then there it was, in the second town i visited. thanks

Comment: The fiery soul trap is a unique enchantment, there is only 1 weapon in the game that has it and it's not for sale.

Answer (score 14):

If you complete the optional objective in the Dark Brotherhood quest [Mourning Never Comes](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Mourning_Never_Comes) you get Muiri's ring which has Fortify Alchemy 15%, I believe. That's the only unique item I can think of off-hand.

Answer (score 8):

If you speak to Frida the alchemist in Dawnstar, she may give you a quest to retrieve the Ring of Pure Mixtures, which gives a bonus to Alchemy. When you return the ring to her, you can pickpocket it back and disenchant it to learn Fortify Alchemy.

Alternatively, you may eventually find one in a dungeon or by pickpocketing an alchemist or mage.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the coin you should be able to find the Circlet of Minor Alchemy (a 12% boost) at Sadri's Used Wares in Windhelm, and both the Circlet of Major Alchemy (a 17% boost) and the Circlet of Eminent Alchemy (a 20% boost) at Radiant Raiments in Solitude. If they're not in stock, just wait 48 hours or reload your game and they should show up.

A chest in the cave at the Halted Stream camp has the Hide Bracers of Alchemy which gives you a 15% boost.

If you kill Krosis at Shearpoint you can loot his mask from his body. His mask will give lockpicking, archery, and alchemy a 20% boost.

The Ring of Pure Mixtures is in a chest in the Forsaken Cave and will give you a 12% boost.

Muri's Ring has a boost of 15% and you get it from Muri as a reward for doing the optional objective in the Mourning Never Comes Dark Brotherhood quest.

There are a few other objects you can find to boost alchemy, but they found by looting random chests once you reach various levels.

Comment: You should be able to get the one in the Halted Stream Camp pretty early. It's the one near Whiterun where they are massacring those poor mammoths. Don't forget to grab the Transmute spell while you're there, and make sure to get the quest for the Halted Stream Camp from Farkas from the Companions first; it's the first one he gives you.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of unique enchanted items, there aren't any. You'll need to either find a random enchanted item in a chest/on an enemy or try and find one in a general store/blacksmith.

You don't need a good piece of gear to learn the enchantment, just something with the enchantment on it.

Comment: As per Daywatch's and Jonathan Drain's answers, your first sentence is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the vendors do not carry the exact same items when loading a savegame. This worked *against* me actually once as I expected to be able to buy something they had in stock after loading a savegame. However if you want to take advantage of it, I noticed as well that after a couple reloads the merchant's inventory no longer changes.

So you might try reload a couple times, see what comes up.

Conversely, if you see something interesting and you want to take a break, consider buying it before quitting the game as it may not be there when you reload your save.

Answer (score -1):

Go to the mining cave at Dawnstar. There should be two trees to the left. The tree on the right has some rocks on its right side. If you look carefully it will say open chest. Take all then go to the Khajiit trader outside of town. Look at her and save the game then hit her. Reload the game, look at her inventory and then repeat. Hopefully you will find it but if not the bright side is that you will get a lot of money. P.S. bring a horse and find a good place to store stuff. Also, if the trader is not there just wait a few days.

Comment: This would be a more useful answer if it explained the purpose of this seemingly-unrelated series of actions.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way that I've found is exploiting the Dawnstar Hidden chest glitch a couple times until something spawns

Answer (score -3):

Go to a random smith or alchemist or any other vendor which sells enchanted items, and check their inventory. If they have such an item, great; if not, save the game, kill them and reload, it should update the inventory. Repeat as necessary.