# Where can I find an item that can be disenchanted to learn "resist fire?"

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can i find an item to to give me the Fortify alchemy enchantment?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38893/where-can-i-find-an-item-to-to-give-me-the-fortify-alchemy-enchantment)

Is there anywhere that I can find an item that is enchanted with fire resist other than hoping for it to pop up in random loot?

Fire breathing dragons keep kicking my ass so I want to learn the enchantment to put on my shield and boots.

Comment: I realize that Resist Fire and Fortify Alchemy are not the same effect, but I'm afraid if I *don't* close this, it opens the door for 20 other questions of, "where can I find X echantment?". What would be better would be a single question asking about non-random loot suitable for disenchanting.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Fair enough :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the most part, it's random loot. The one placed Resist Fire piece I can think of -- [Ancient Helmet of the Unburned](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Ancient_Helmet_of_the_Unburned) -- can't be disenchanted. Of course, that might also be the solution, since it grants 40% resistance. You get it in a dungeon during a College of Winterhold quest. Otar's also nice (30% resist against all elements).

But if you're not ready for some tough bosses, you can either get lucky with loot, or just visit armor sellers until one of them sells it.

Or you can create a potion, since this has a very specific, time-limited purpose. Any pairing of the following will work: Bone Meal, Dragon's Tongue, Elves Ear, Fire Salts, Fly Amanita, Mudcrab Chitin or Snowberries.