# Where can I find  items to Disenchant?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim there are a number of Enchantments availble for you to enchant your weapons and armour with, which can be gained from disenchanting a weapon which already contained said enchantment.

Most enchantments can be found on vendors, but depending on your luck, it might take needlessly long to find a certain enchantment, and I'm interested in other options.

What I'm looking for is a more consistent method to get specific enchantments. Non-random enchanted items (like quest rewards) are a certain way to get it, but may not be available for all possible enchantments.

What non-random, disenchantable items are available in Skyrim?

Comment: Note that this is the generic version of: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38893 and http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41044

Answer (score 7):

Here's a start (its a CW so feel free to add to the list)

Fortify Alchemy - Muiri's Ring - [Mourning Never Comes](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Mourning_Never_Comes)

Fortify Magicka - Novice Hood - Intro Dungeon (in locked cell)

Fortify Magicka Regeneration - Novice Robes - Intro Dungeon (in locked cell)

Resist Magicka (Stronger version) - Shield of Solitude - [Wolf Queen Awakened](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Wolf_Queen_Awakened)

Fortify Unarmed Damage - Gloves of the Pugilist - [The Ratway](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Ratway)

Absorb Health - Blade of Woe or Drainblood Battleaxe - Astrid or Labyrinthian

Briarheart Geis - Briarheart Geis - Lost Valley Redoubt

Silent Moons Enchantment - Any Silent Moons Weapon - Silent Moons camp

Smithing Expertise - Notched Pickaxe - found at the very top of The Throat of the World.

Notes:

Axe of Whiterun will always come with 1 random weapon enchantment