# where can I find frost enchanted weapon

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find  items to Disenchant?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41060/where-can-i-find-items-to-disenchant)

I need to find a frost enchated weapon (like the Imperial Bow Of Chills) to learn the frost
damage enchant? Mostly I need it for my bow, so that I can finally slow down giants.

Answers with any weapon any level any kind will do, I just need something with frost damage.

Answer (score 3):

You can try finding one of the unique weapons listed here:
http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Frost_Damage

Or you could try finding one in Bleak Falls Barrow, apparently the boss over there always drops a frost enchanted weapon.

Comment: well thanks, can't get the weapon from bleak falls barrow (did it long time ago) I guess i will look for another thing, and luckily when hidden I can finally one shot them but I will still need it for other cases.